# How can we set inheritance object in python

Tags: python, oop

I am having a problem in simple code I wrote

Class Point  has x and y values

Class square (Point) includes 4 points : p1,p2,p3,p4

I am trying to update x value of p1 for example with sq1.p1.set_x(num1) and failed.

I tried to work with public defnition but also failed

Whot is my problem ? Thanks

```py
class Point:
    def __init__(self,x=0,y=0):
        self.__x = x
        self.__y = y
           
    def get_x(self):
        return self.__x
    
    def get_y(self):
        return self.__y
    
    def set_x(self,x=0):
        self.__x = x
    
    def set_y(self,y=0):
        self.__y = y
  

class Square (Point):
    def __init__(self,p1,p2,p3,p4):
        self.__p1 = p1
        self.__p2 = p2
        self.__p3 = p3
        self.__p4 = p4
            
    def get_p1(self):
        return self.__p1
    
    def get_p2(self):
        return self.__p2
    
    def get_p3(self):
        return self.__p3
    
    def get_p4(self):
        return self.__p4
    
    def set_p1(self,p1):
        self.__p1 = p1
    
    def set_p2(self,p2):
        self.__p2 = p2
    
    def set_p3(self,p1):
        self.__p3 = p3
    
    def set_p4(self,p4):
        self.__p4 = p4


def main():

    p1 = Point(2,0)
    p2 = Point(2,2)
    p3 = Point(0,2)
    p4 = Point(0,0)

    sq1 = Square(p1,p2,p3,p4)
    sq1.p1.set_x(4) # this line failing

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Your `set_p3` method has a typo, `p3` is undefined

Comment: Thanks - I fixed it but the problem still there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
    sq1.p1.set_x(4) # this line failing
```

with

```
    sq1.get_p1().set_x(4)
```

This is because class `Square` doesn't have a `p1` property (it has a `__p1` property, but not `p1`).

Comment: Sorry - How can I do that - New here

Comment: No problem; see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: I never asked a question on this site, so that's why I refer you to a page explaining it.  But there should be a checkmark next to my answer which only you can see and I can't, and that should be clicked. And then there is a triangle pointing upwards which should also be clicked.